# Converting a .net code into php giving issue at split

Tags: php, .net, web-applications

In want to read a text based rpt file and show its data column by column. I have a .net code as below which works fine:

```
if (long.TryParse(str1.Substring(0, 7), out result))
{
 str1.Split('|');
 string str2 = str1.Substring(194, 16);
}
```

I tried to write the same code in php as below:

```
if((int)substr($str1,0,7))
{
 $str1=split('\|', $str1);
 echo $str2 = substr($str1,194, 16);
}
else
{
 echo "<br>";
}
```

It says:

> split(): REG_EMPTY

Please suggest an update in the code that can make the above php code work same like .net code.

Comment: Check the documentation of `split`. Looks like it interprets your input as an invalid (empty) regular expression, while you want it to be interpreted as a verbatim string? Removing the backslash might help, or maybe `split` has an extra parameter to distinguish between string and regex argument.

Comment: @ITSagar : Which version of PHP you are using. 
Better to not use split() function.
It is deprecated in PHP 5.3.0 and remove in PHP 7.0.0

Comment: @RolandWeber I tried it without slash but seems like | is a token in php so it needs to be escaped. Secondaly, in actual rpt file, there is no | symbol visible but the .net code runs fine, while php code doesnt

Comment: @ImranKhan Google says .net split function generates substrings while php split function generates arrays. I need something equivalent to .net split()

Comment: @ITSagar Can you add some sample data and expected result. That will be more better.